# Where to ask questions about writing plugins and scripts for QGIS?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have started delving into python stuff for QGIS and my questions are not really of interest to most users of GIS SE.

Where should I ask questions about writing plugins and scripts for QGIS?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure that there is such a thing as "the main group" here, because Python questions come from multiple audiences e.g. [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) and [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), as well as the generic [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).

However, specific audiences are easily reached here via careful tagging of your Questions e.g. [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins), [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis), [shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapely), etc.

If your Python Questions are GIS specific then they are on-topic for [GIS SE (Main)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).  However, if they are pure Python, and would standalone with no mention of a GIS technology in them, then a more suitable place to ask them is [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

I wrote the above before spotting "qgis" on the end of your title.  However, I think most if not all of it still applies so I will refrain from changing it for now.  My understanding is that a question title should only summarise what is in the Question body, so if you are looking for Answers related specifically to QGIS then you may want to edit your Question to make that clear.