# Is the [tag:qgis-plugins] tag for questions about *writing* plugins, or questions about *using* plugins?

Tags: discussion

The [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) tag has three main categories of questions:

1. Questions by people who are developing a plugin. These questions tend to be highly technical, and involve pyqgis code.

   - Example: [Object has no attribute "dlg"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343755/object-has-no-attribute-dlg)
2. Questions by people who are *using* a plugin - these questions range from "how do I use this plugin" to "why am I getting this error when I run this plugin." These questions tend to be less technical.

   - Example: [QGIS2web not updating](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344028/qgis2web-not-updating)
   - Example: [QGIS having issue loading plugin "Profilefrompoints"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343934/qgis-having-issue-loading-plugin-profilefrompoints)
3. Questions from people who are *looking for* a plugin. These questions are prone to the XY problem, where they want a solution for their problem and have (correctly or incorrectly) assumed that the solution will be a plugin.

   - Example: [Drawing rectangle with geo coordinates (north/south, east/west) using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344105/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-geo-coordintes-north-south-east-west)?

The tag wiki doesn't specify which of these types of questions should have the [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) tag. It reads:

> Software plugins that add functionality to the QGIS package
>
> QGIS has a plugin infrastructure. You can add a lot of new functionality by writing your own plugins. These plugins can either be written in C++ or in Python.
>
> - [QGIS Plugin development](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/plugindevelopment.html)
> - [QGIS Plugins](http://plugins.qgis.org/)

---

I found these related GIS-meta questions, none of which really address this question:

- [Where do questions about QGIS plugin development belong?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/where-do-questions-about-qgis-plugin-development-belong)
- [Should we reorganize sextante, sextante-qgis-plugin, and qgis-processing tags?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/should-we-reorganize-sextante-sextante-qgis-plugin-and-qgis-processing-tags)
- [Where to ask questions about writing plugins and scripts for QGIS?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/where-to-ask-questions-about-writing-plugins-and-scripts-for-qgis/3618#3618)

### Which type(s) of question *should* have the [qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugin) tag?

What prompted this question, is recently I saw [Drawing rectangle with geo coordinates (north/south, east/west) using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344105)  where the asker wanted to know how to draw a rectangle from given coordinates. That question would have one answer if they want to do it as a regular QGIS user, but it would have another answer if they wanted to do it in a plugin they're writing. The asker had tagged the question [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) because they thought maybe the solution would be a plugin. To me that seems like not the right use of the tag, but there's nothing in the tag description that would have told them otherwise.

Comment: Is there any reason it can't be for _both_?

Comment: @Midavalo That's what I'm asking. To me they seem like extremely different categories, with different purposes and userbases. I'd like to clarify the tag wiki, but I want to know what the community thinks. Would you post your opinion as an answer so people can vote on it?

Answer (score 5):

First, I agree that using [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) is not the right use for that tag in that question.  That tag probably shouldn't be on the question at all, that way an answerer could provide an answer for QGIS itself, or for a plugin that could potentially solve the problem.

I believe, however, that the tag could/should be used for **both** - for questions relating to how to use a plugin, as well as questions about how to write a plugin.  Subsequent tags could then be used that would narrow the focus of the question to usage or writing.

For example, another broad usage tag is [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) which is used by people needing help using ArcGIS Desktop, as well as by people asking for help while writing scripts or tools for ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: So, you think the categories 1 and 2 should be on this tag, but category 3 should not? Or category 3 questions are okay sometimes, depending on the specific question?

Comment: @csk That kinda enters into the area of XY problems.  Better for a question to be asked stating the problem, and a plugin might be a potential solution.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, the [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) tag seems to currently be placed on three main categories of questions:

1. Questions by people who are **developing a plugin**.

I think that these should be tagged with [qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugin) and [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) (or [c++](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and not with [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) because the potential answerers are most likely to be PyQGIS (or C++) developers who probably have [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) (or [c++](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) set in their filters.

2. Questions by people who are **using a plugin**.

I think that these should be tagged with [qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugin) and [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis), and not with [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) because the potential answerers are most likely to be QGIS users who probably have [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) set in their filters.

3. Questions from people who are **looking for a plugin recommendation**.

I think that these should be tagged with [software-recommendation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation), [qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugin) and [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis), and not with [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) because the potential answerers are most likely to be QGIS users who probably have [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) set in their filters.

To improve the [qgis-plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-plugins) tag wiki I would propose something like:

> QGIS has a plugin infrastructure. You can add a lot of new
>   functionality by writing your own plugins. These plugins can either be
>   written in C++ or in Python.
>
> - [QGIS Plugin development](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/plugindevelopment.html)
> - [QGIS Plugins](http://plugins.qgis.org/)
>
> If you asking about a QGIS plugin that you are **developing** also tag it
>   with [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis) or [c++](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
>
> If you asking about a QGIS plugin that you are **using** also tag it with
>   [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis).
>
> If you are **looking for** a QGIS plugin also tag it with
>   [software-recommendations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) and [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis), and provide a detailed
>   description of your requirements, the QGIS plugins you have already
>   reviewed against them, and how those QGIS plugins failed to meet them.